# Change the position of a smart button in ODOO

Tags: button, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

To change the position of the smart button whether it is inherited or newly created, it is a method to add this in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code

```
        <field name="priority" eval="99" />
```

Add this line like this:

```
<record id="view_custom_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="99" />
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
```

The priority in this code is which position that button should be placed